# "Google.Ads.Common" reference is not added in ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

how I can add this reference in my project please help me.I am doing this project in mvc6 using asp.net framework 6

Answer (score 0):

Ask google nicely to support .NET Core. Only they can fix their packages.

Comment: please refer to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194075/reference-is-not-added-in-asp-net-mvc-6-for-microsoft-bingads-sdk