# reference is not added in ASP.Net MVC 6 for "Microsoft.BingAds.SDK”

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I am doing this project in mvc6 using asp.net framework 6.how I can add this reference in my project please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to talk to BingAds and ask them for a compatible version. This is the same with every library provider, they all must support the new platform. You cannot add a library which targets .NET 4.x, they must rewrite and publish a new version/